# Search a list for items that are within a certain range of each other?

Tags: python, sorting, range, items

I am simulating the life cycle of certain organisms. I have created a list which sorts them by their x coordinate on a grid, like so:

```
organisms.sort(key = lambda x: x.position[0])
```

The list of organisms consists of 'animals' defined by their position and sex.

I would like to now extract elements of that list that are within a certain range of each other, say within a radius (+- value on x axis, +- value on y axis) and put those on another list.

Comment: Please share a sample

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please have a look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: This would be easier in numpy. You need to create a distance matrix with your list (it doesnt need to be ordered) each row/col index is an animal, for each row (or col) take the min k values (you could use `np.argsort`).  Its the same without numpy, you will just need to write more code. Hope this helps!